# Exterior power of the direct sum of projective modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, exterior-algebra, projective-module

Can someone please point out to a (quite) detailled proof of the following result ? thanks in advance.

Let $P$, $Q$ be finitely generated projective $R-$modules, of respective rank $n$ and $m$. then we have

$(\bigwedge^n P) \bigotimes_R (\bigwedge^m Q) \cong \bigwedge^{n+m} (P \bigoplus Q) $

Comment: Only if $n = \dim P$ and $m = \dim Q$ for appropriate notions of $\dim$ (which might require a bit more than projectivity for $P$ and $Q$).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your remark, i just edited the post.

Comment: The main thing to know is the canonical isomorphism $\Lambda\left(P\otimes Q\right) \cong \left(\Lambda P\right) \otimes \left(\Lambda Q\right)$ of graded algebras. Taking the $n+m$-th degree part of it, we obtain a canonical isomorphism $\Lambda^{n+m}\left(P\otimes Q\right) \cong \bigoplus\limits_{k=0}^{n+m} \left(\Lambda^k P\right) \otimes \left(\Lambda^{n+m-k} Q\right)$. Now, if $n$ and $m$ are ranks of $P$ and $Q$ in the appropriate sense (you have to be careful -- in general, a rank of a projective module is not a number), then ...

Comment: ... all the addends on the right hand side of this are zero except for the addend for $k = n$. For the algebra isomorphism I've used, a source is §II.3.7 of [Nicolas Bourbaki, *Algebra I, Chapters 1-3*, Addison-Wesley 1974](https://archive.org/details/ElementsOfMathematics-AlgebraPart1) (which you probably can easily read in its original French).